# Set user's profile picture on Tabbar item

Tags: swift, tabbar

Set profile image(received from url) on Tabbar item. 
I am expecting the updated profile image on `TabBarItem`.

**Expected output**

[image]

Comment: stackoverflow is not code service. Please show what have you tried so far

Comment: I have used :

    let myTabBarItem5 = (self.tabBar.items?[4])! as UITabBarItem

        let imgView : UIImageView =  UIImageView()
        imgView.setImage_kf(imageString: UserModel.main.profilePic, placeHolderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icTabbarProfilePlaceholder"))

        let  img = imgView.image
        myTabBarItem5.image = img?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78124943/227148

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [blog](https://iosrevisited.blogspot.com/2019/08/add-imageview-profile-picture-to-tabbar-swift-ios.html) and it works. I made a change to it and used an image instead of the image name.

1- make an extension on `UITabBar` and add the this method below

```
import UIKit

extension UITabBarController {
    
    func addSubviewToLastTabItem(_ image: UIImage) {
        
        if let lastTabBarButton = self.tabBar.subviews.last, let tabItemImageView = lastTabBarButton.subviews.first {
            if let accountTabBarItem = self.tabBar.items?.last {
                accountTabBarItem.selectedImage = nil
                accountTabBarItem.image = nil // be careful with this line, this might cause a crash in newer versions of Xcode
            }
            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.frame = tabItemImageView.frame
            imgView.layer.cornerRadius = tabItemImageView.frame.height/2
            imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.clipsToBounds = true
            imgView.image = image
            self.tabBar.subviews.last?.addSubview(imgView)
        }
    }
}
```

2- to use it

```
let yourImage = UIImage(named: "your-image")

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { // add to any vc
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    tabBarController?.addSubviewToLastTabItem(yourImage)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController:ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
    let profileTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "SEARCH", image: UIImage(named: "profile_Image"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "search_selected"))
    profileTabBarItem.tag = 0
    viewController.tabBarItem = profileTabBarItem
    let viewControllerNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)
```