# Image on tabItem, UIKit UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbar

I'm making an app with UIKit and I want to set a profile image (received from url) on a tabbar item. I am expecting the updated profile image on tabbar item. I also want to add a border around the image when the tab is selected.

I found this solution, but the image does not appear in the tabitem.
[Set user's profile picture on Tabbar item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141614/set-users-profile-picture-on-tabbar-item)

```
extension UITabBarController {
    func addSubviewToLastTabItem(_ image: UIImage) {
        if let lastTabBarButton = self.tabBar.subviews.last, let tabItemImageView = lastTabBarButton.subviews.first {
            if let accountTabBarItem = self.tabBar.items?.last {
                accountTabBarItem.selectedImage = nil
                accountTabBarItem.image = nil
            }
            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.frame = tabItemImageView.frame
            imgView.layer.cornerRadius = tabItemImageView.frame.height/2
            imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.clipsToBounds = true
            imgView.image = image
            self.tabBar.subviews.last?.addSubview(imgView)
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to do that?

Comment: Where are you calling this function from?

Comment: @SimeonRumy from viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the second part of code:

```
 let yourImage = UIImage(named: "your-image")

 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { // add to any vc
 super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

 tabBarController?.addSubviewToLastTabItem(yourImage) 
 }
```

When you call addSubviewToLastTabItem("String") it is critical print correctly parameter without mistakes.

Could you post this part of code?

One more thing viewDidLayoutSubviews will work if you rotate iPhone, double check please that you are calling addSubviewToLastTabItem() in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as setting the image to the `UITabBarItem`, the only caveat is that you need to make sure the image's rendering mode is set to [UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode/alwaysoriginal), otherwise the image will be treated as a template and coloured based on the tint you are using on your `UITabBar`

For example, on your UIViewController you'd do the following:

```
let avatar = imageReceivedFromUrl.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
self.tabBarItem.image = avatar
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = avatar
```

Source:

> The system provides several tab bar items for common use cases. If you need a custom item, create one with a title and an image. You can further customize the item by providing an alternate image that appears when the user selects it. By default, the item doesn’t display the images you provide. Instead, it generates new images from the alpha values of your images and tints them. To prevent this, provide images that use the [UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode/alwaysoriginal) rendering mode.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem